# Login to a school system and get account type

Tags: php, database, authentication, mysqli

I'm new to MySQL database design.
My question is this database is correctly built or not.
We used the users table to login and get account type [image]

and here the code to login

```
 $result = mysqli_query($db->_connect()," SELECT * FROM users WHERE nam = $_n AND pas = $_p ");

if (!empty($result)) {
    // check for empty result
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $response["userInfo"] = array(); 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $userInfo = array();
            $userInfo["id"] = $row["id"];
            $userInfo["id_school"] = $row["id_school"]; 
            $userInfo["states"] = $row["states"];
            $userInfo["a_type"] = $row["a_type"];               
            array_push($response["userInfo"], $userInfo);
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! I find it slightly unsettling to be presented code with unmatched braces or parentheses.

Comment: I have several questions: 1. What is an user? In other words: Why does an user need `id_school`, `states` and `a_type`. The last two don't mean anything to me. 2. Why do you abbreviate names? `$_n` and `nam`, really? Why not `$username` and `username`? Code should not be a puzzle. 3. You insert PHP variables directly into your query string. That's like opening the door to your palace and invite the riff-raff. Please read up on [SQL-injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). 4. Why do you, seemingly, allow multiple users to log in at the same time?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware the 1-user need id_school to add the user to that school case we have multiple school and same login screen to student and school so we make the users table  states if the account is disable on not a_type account type school or student 2- this php script for android app not web app and i'am new to php

Comment: @KIKOSoftware for php insert i will use this   
    $stmt = $db->_connect()->prepare(" SELECT * FROM users WHERE nam = ? AND pas = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_n,$_p);
    $result =  $stmt->execute();

Comment: That is indeed better. However, the problem with the names remains. How will anyone know what `$_n` or `$_p` stand for? Also, if I had to guess I would say that `id_std` is a student id, but why not call it `student_id` or `student_number`? similarly `sc_nam` should probably be called `school_name`. This will make your code a lot easier to read. 30 years ago we used abbreviations to save memory, but nowadays most computers have enough memory to store a normal sensible name.

Comment: I believe this code is not working yes and therefore the question would likely be closed. Please test your code before posting it here.

Comment: @YourCommonSense This code worked

Answer (score -1):

This code work for me

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND _password= ?';

if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_username, $_password); // 's' specifies the variable type => 'string'
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $response["userInfo"] = array();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            // Do something with $row
            $userInfo = array();
            $userInfo["id"] = $row["id"];
            $userInfo["id_school"] = $row["id_school"];
            $userInfo["states"] = $row["states"];
            $userInfo["account_type"] = $row["account_type"];
            array_push($response["userInfo"], $userInfo);
        }

        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Login Done";
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Fail to Login";
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: You are not supposed to post an edited code as an answer. I would suggest to delete the current question and to ask a new one, adding the code you posted here.